# Why is there a mystery margin between Select elements?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/eja79nme/1/)

```
<select>test</select>
<select>test</select>
<select>test</select>
```

I'm trying to add stuff between the select elements, but I'm unable to get them aligned properly because select elements naturally have a margin between them. Looking through the computed styles I'm unable to figure out why this is the case.

How do I remove this? Do I have to result to negative margins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select elements are **inline-block elements** by default and like all inline-block (or inline) elements they have a "white space" between them like inline words in a sentence.

Check [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) for ways to remove that white space or use `display:block;` to make them block elements without white space.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/eja79nme/3/)

Comment: "...the size of the white space depends on browser." Does it? It depends on the width of the space glyph of the font in use, but if you used a custom font, wouldn't that precisely define the negative margin to use?

Comment: @Alohci you are right, I'll remove that sentence, it is wrong